# Variable types mess

Tags: c++, optimization, arduino

Why do I do not get normal results in the following code?

```
void Motors::setCycleDutyA(int percentage) {
    Serial.println(percentage);
    Serial.println(pwmCycleDutyA);
    float x=percentage/100;
    Serial.print(x);
    pwmCycleDutyA = int(255*x);
    Serial.println(pwmCycleDutyA);
}
```

When I call the function:

```
Motors::setCycleDutyA(45);
```

I get these results:

> 45    255      0.000
>
> 45    0        0.000
>
> 45    0        0.000

What do I miss?

Comment: 255 is the predefined number for pwmCycleDutyA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `float x = percentage / 100`, where `percentage` is of type `int`. This means both arguments of `/` are integral, and therefore integer division is performed. Then, the result is converted to `float`.

You want this:

```
float x = percentage / 100.f;
```

Or just change the type of `percentage` to `float`.

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
float x=percentage/100;
```

You are performing **integer division** (since both operands are integer). This means that the result will be `0` every time `percentage` is less than `100`. That explains the results you are getting.

Change it into:

```
float x=percentage/static_cast<float>(100);
```

Or alternatively:

```
float x=percentage/100.f;
```

Comment: if we do something like this: int x=3  int y=5 and float z=x/y that means that z will not be correct?

Comment: @kyrpav: Depends on what you mean by "correct": for the rules of the language, that's correct :) If you want to perform floating point division, then one of the operands needs to be a floating point number. If you have integer variables to begin with, just use `static_cast<float>` on at least one of them, as I've shown in the answer

Answer (score 1):

For a situation like this, I'd tend to avoid using floating point. Code to control a motor like this often runs on a small microcontroller that doesn't support floating point directly, so floating point computations are often emulated in software, which is slow and can add quite a bit of extra code.

Therefore, I'd try to consider whether this can be done in integer math instead. Looking at the sequence:

```
float x=percentage/100;
pwmCycleDutyA = int(255*x);
```

This is basically equivalent to:

```
pwbCycleDutyA = percentage * 2.55;
```

For quite a few purposes, it's sufficient to treat that as `percentage * 2.5`, which is pretty easy to render in integer math:

```
pwbCycleDutyA = (percentage * 5) / 2;
```

This reduces the range of values we can produce to 0..250 instead of 0..255 -- but keep in mind that since the percentage is starting as an `int`, we can only generate 100 discrete values in any case, so this is rarely likely to make much (if any) difference.

If, however, you're certain the multiplier really needs to be 2.55 instead of 2.5, you can do that too. The most obvious is to simply rearrange your equation -- instead of dividing by 100 then multiplying by 255, multiply by 255 first, then divide by 100:

```
pwbCycleDutyA = (percentage * 255) / 100;
```

The main thing to keep in mind in rearranging an equation like this is ensuring against overflow. Assuming `percentage` never exceeds 100, we're pretty safe though -- the intermediate result can never exceed `25500`, which fits easily in a signed 16-bit int (the smallest that C allows).